# Limits of functions in metric spaces

Tags: analysis, limits, metric-spaces

My teacher said that in the definition of limit, the point in the domain, must be of accumulation, because otherwise the limit is not unique. Why? If the point is isolated, the function is continuous, therefore admits limit. (in a metric space $X$, a point of subset $A$, or it's of accumulation for $A$ or it's isolated)

Answer (score 1):

The concept of limit of a function only makes sense when all deleted neighbourhood of the point is $\ne\emptyset$. For the limit, the value of the function *in* the point is *irrelevent*, only depents of the behavior of the function *near* the point.

Using the most general definition (Wikipedia):

"For every open neighborhood $V$ of $L$ [the limit], there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ [the point] such that $f(U\setminus\{p\})\subset V$."

If we have an *empty* deleted neighborhood $U\setminus\{p\}$, then $f(U\setminus\{p\})=\emptyset\subset V$ always and anything is a limit.

Comment: thanks!!! but the question was another..why the point, if is not of accumulation, the limit would not be unique??? she said this

Comment: See the edit...

Answer (score 0):

If we read the definition of $\lim_{x \to p} f(x)=q$, sooner or later we find the sentence "provided that $|x-p|<\delta$ and $x \neq p$". Therefore, as somebody else said in an answer, the standard definition must assume that there are points $x$ arbitrarily close to $p$ but different from $p$. Hence $p$ must be an accumulation point of the domain of $f$.

You should not confuse limits and continuity, since continuity at isolated point is trivially granted. Limits are useful as long as you approach a point that can be approached in a non-trivial way.